# Spawning a diagram generated by GNUPLOT on Windows

Tags: windows, gnuplot, spawn

I am writing a software for phase diagrams and I use GNUPLOT which works very nicely.  I develop the software on Windows but it works on all platforms with a Fortran compiler, I use GNU Fortran 4.8

My problem is to spawn a plot window on Windows.  Inside the program I generate a gnuplot command file ending with "pause mouse" and use a system
command to run gnuplot with this file.  It means I have to close the plot window to continue generating another.  The option -persist does not work. If I plot the same file outside the program the plot windows remanins open and I can continue.

I have seen several answers to this question but none that works for me.

Bo Sundman

Comment: Related? https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1145/ and  http://superuser.com/questions/881821/automatically-open-a-file-when-gnuplot-starts-on-windows On my Mac, any combination of "pause mouse" and -persist seems to work, so a problem specific to Windows?

Comment: Do you use pause mouse to get interactivity? May be another terminal would work as expected?

Comment: I tested on GNUPLOT with my software my MAC and it behaves complely the opposite, it does not stop on "pause mouse" and all plot windows are spawed automatically.  On MAC I use an X11 terminal, on Windows I use wxt, there is no terminal in common.  I know there are other terminals but I am not very familiar installing software on MAC.

Comment: I think that wxt is by default interactive,  so I would try to remove 'pause mouse'  or change to the qt terminal. Install the gnuplot-qt package if necessary.